# $.each returns 'undefined is not an object'

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, loops

I have the following problem.

I have this JSON feed set up: https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ukdk

And I'm trying to iterate through the source to eventually output to html.

```
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ukdk', function (tabledata) {
        var items = []; 
        console.log(tabledata);
        //To get category name
        var categoryName = tabledata.Categorie;    
        var title, advertisement, day;
        $.each(tabledata.titles, function () {
                title = this;
                //to get title name and value
                var titleName = title.Naam,
                        titleValue = title.Waarde;
                $.each(title.advertisements, function(){
                        advertisement = this;
                        //to get advertisement name
                        var advertisementName = advertisement.Naam;                
                        $.each(advertisement.days, function(){
                                day = this;
                                //to get date
                                var advertisementDay = day.Datum;     
                        });
                });        
        });
        //$(items.join('')).appendTo('table');
});
```

When I output (tabledata) to the console I get this object, filled with objects within arrays (which is okay, I guess).

However, I get this error on the $.each function:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.length')
```

I cannot seem to get my head around the problem. It seems I cannot address table data.titles directly. Any help / suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: in any case either title.advertisements or advertisement.days  can be undefined or null  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your feed is returning an array of objects. You can loop through the titles by accessing the first array item directly.

```
$.each(tabledata[0].titles, function () {
```

Comment: It's always the simple ones which take the longest to solve :)

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your JSON response. The reason your code is not working is because `tabledata` itself is an `Array` but you treat it like the first object inside it.

If you really are just interested in the first element, use `tabledata[0]` to access it. If you're interested in every possible element, you will need to iterate over `tabledata` and deal with each element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is some problem in your JSON parsing

Actual JSON looks like this

```
[{
        "Categorie" : "Tijdschrift",
        "Aantal scans" : 1200,
        "Aantal bestellingen" : 729,
        "Conversie" : "61%",
        "Waarde" : 3608.55,
        "titles" : [{
                "Naam" : "Libelle",
                "Aantal Aantal scans" : 214,
                "Aantal bestelingen" : 118,
                "Waarde" : 1089.33,
                "advertisements" : [{
                        "id" : 0,
                        "Advertentie" : "Wasmachine 3",
                        "Aantal Aantal scans" : 400,
                        "Aantal bestellingen" : 243,
                        "Conversie" : "61%",
                        "Waarde" : 1202.85,
                        "days" : [{
                                "Datum" : "8 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 20,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 11,
                                "Waarde" : 99
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "9 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 88,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 42,
                                "Waarde" : 435.6
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "10 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 76,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 43,
                                "Waarde" : 376.2
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "11 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 30,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 22,
                                "Waarde" : 148.5
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "Advertentie" : "Anders",
                        "Aantal scans" : 400,
                        "Aantal bestellingen" : 243,
                        "conversion" : "61%",
                        "Waarde" : 1202.85,
                        "days" : [{
                                "Datum" : "8 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 20,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 11,
                                "Waarde" : 99
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "9 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 88,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 42,
                                "Waarde" : 435.6
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "10 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 76,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 43,
                                "Waarde" : 376.2
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "11 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 30,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 22,
                                "Waarde" : 148.5
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "id" : 2,
                        "Advertentie" : "Wasmachine 4",
                        "Aantal scans" : 400,
                        "Aantal bestellingen" : 243,
                        "conversion" : "61%",
                        "Waarde" : 1202.85,
                        "days" : [{
                                "Datum" : "8 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 20,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 11,
                                "Waarde" : 99
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "9 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 88,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 42,
                                "Waarde" : 435.6
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "10 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 76,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 43,
                                "Waarde" : 376.2
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "11 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 30,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 22,
                                "Waarde" : 148.5
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "Advertentie" : "Beau Monde",
                "Aantal scans" : 782,
                "Aantal bestellingen" : 33,
                "Waarde" : 9238.33,
                "advertisements" : [{
                        "id" : 0,
                        "Advertentie" : "Wasmachine 3",
                        "Aantal scans" : 400,
                        "Aantal bestellingen" : 243,
                        "conversion" : "61%",
                        "Waarde" : 1202.85,
                        "days" : [{
                                "Datum" : "8 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 20,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 11,
                                "Waarde" : 99
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "9 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 88,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 42,
                                "Waarde" : 435.6
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "10 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 76,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 43,
                                "Waarde" : 376.2
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "11 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 30,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 22,
                                "Waarde" : 148.5
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "Advertentie" : "Anders",
                        "Aantal scans" : 400,
                        "Aantal bestellingen" : 243,
                        "conversion" : "61%",
                        "Waarde" : 1202.85,
                        "days" : [{
                                "Datum" : "8 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 20,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 11,
                                "Waarde" : 99
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "9 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 88,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 42,
                                "Waarde" : 435.6
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "10 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 76,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 43,
                                "Waarde" : 376.2
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "11 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 30,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 22,
                                "Waarde" : 148.5
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "id" : 2,
                        "Advertentie" : "Wasmachine 4",
                        "Aantal scans" : 400,
                        "Aantal bestellingen" : 243,
                        "conversion" : "61%",
                        "Waarde" : 1202.85,
                        "days" : [{
                                "Datum" : "8 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 20,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 11,
                                "Waarde" : 99
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "9 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 88,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 42,
                                "Waarde" : 435.6
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "10 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 76,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 43,
                                "Waarde" : 376.2
                            }, {
                                "Datum" : "11 mei",
                                "Aantal scans" : 30,
                                "Aantal bestellingen" : 22,
                                "Waarde" : 148.5
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

After parsing what we get is this

```
[{
        "id" : 0,
        "Advertentie" : "Wasmachine 3",
        "Aantal scans" : 400,
        "Aantal bestellingen" : 243,
        "conversion" : "61%",
        "Waarde" : 1202.85,
        "days" : [{
                "Datum" : "8 mei",
                "Aantal scans" : 20,
                "Aantal bestellingen" : 11,
                "Waarde" : 99
            }, {
                "Datum" : "9 mei",
                "Aantal scans" : 88,
                "Aantal bestellingen" : 42,
                "Waarde" : 435.6
            }, {
                "Datum" : "10 mei",
                "Aantal scans" : 76,
                "Aantal bestellingen" : 43,
                "Waarde" : 376.2
            }, {
                "Datum" : "11 mei",
                "Aantal scans" : 30,
                "Aantal bestellingen" : 22,
                "Waarde" : 148.5
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id" : 1,
        "Advertentie" : "Anders",
        "Aantal scans" : 400,
        "Aantal bestellingen" : 243,
        "conversion" : "61%",
        "Waarde" : 1202.85,
        "days" : [{
                "Datum" : "8 mei",
                "Aantal scans" : 20,
                "Aantal bestellingen" : 11,
                "Waarde" : 99
            }, {
                "Datum" : "9 mei",
                "Aantal scans" : 88,
                "Aantal bestellingen" : 42,
                "Waarde" : 435.6
            }, {
                "Datum" : "10 mei",
                "Aantal scans" : 76,
                "Aantal bestellingen" : 43,
                "Waarde" : 376.2
            }, {
                "Datum" : "11 mei",
                "Aantal scans" : 30,
                "Aantal bestellingen" : 22,
                "Waarde" : 148.5
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id" : 2,
        "Advertentie" : "Wasmachine 4",
        "Aantal scans" : 400,
        "Aantal bestellingen" : 243,
        "conversion" : "61%",
        "Waarde" : 1202.85,
        "days" : [{
                "Datum" : "8 mei",
                "Aantal scans" : 20,
                "Aantal bestellingen" : 11,
                "Waarde" : 99
            }, {
                "Datum" : "9 mei",
                "Aantal scans" : 88,
                "Aantal bestellingen" : 42,
                "Waarde" : 435.6
            }, {
                "Datum" : "10 mei",
                "Aantal scans" : 76,
                "Aantal bestellingen" : 43,
                "Waarde" : 376.2
            }, {
                "Datum" : "11 mei",
                "Aantal scans" : 30,
                "Aantal bestellingen" : 22,
                "Waarde" : 148.5
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
]
}
]
```

you can see clearly the difference